# Chain rule and differentiability of $|x|^2$

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

Going through Thomas Calculus, question 90 in the chapter on Chain Rule:

> Suppose that $f(x) =x^{2}$ and $g(x) =|x|$. Then the composites
>
> $$
> ( f\circ g)( x) =|x|^{2} =x^{2} \ \ \ \ \ \ and\ \ \ \ \ ( g\circ f)( x) =|x^{2} |=x^{2}
> $$
> are both differentiable at $x=0$ even though $g$ itself is not differentiable at $x=0$. Does this contradict the Chain Rule?

I understand that $|x^{2}|$ is differentiable at $x=0$ because the inner function is differentiable. And the outer function receives only non-negative values, so it also turns out to be differentiable.

But I don't believe that $f\circ g$ is differentiable. While the expression $|x|^{2}$ can be simplified to $x^{2}$, these are in fact different functions. And because the inner $g$ isn't differentiable at $x=0$, the whole composition isn't differentiable at this point.

But **strictly speaking the question itself doesn't sound correct** - it says the composites are both differentiable. But what the author meant is the 3d function $c(x)=x^{2}$ is differentiable. Composites and $c(x)$ are not the same function - they just happen to give the same result.

Do I understand the solution correctly? Is the question posed incorrectly?

Comment: The difference is only syntactic.

Comment: In what regard would $x\mapsto\lvert x\rvert^2$ and $x\mapsto x^2$ be different functions?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio in the same regard as $f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$ and $g(x)=1$ are different functions. One is defined at $x=0$, and the other one isn't. They tend to give the same result, and one can be simplified to another. But if someone asked us what's the value $f(0)$, we can't say it's 1.

Comment: But $|x|^2$ and $x^2$ are both defined at $x=0$.

Comment: You should perhaps return to the part of your textbook that discusses equality of functions. This is a subtle point that takes time to understand: An algebraic expression may help define a function, but it is not a function.

Comment: @user176372, hm.. I thought that functions can be described in multiple ways. In the most abstract way - they're just a mapping between 2 sets. But depending on how we look at it, we could say that the function is _defined_ by an expression, can't we? And in that case, the order of operations matter - a simplified expression may give a valid result, while an explicit composition will be undefined for a given parameter.

Comment: @user176372, I checked how the book defines a function: _A function $f$ from a set $D$ to a set $Y$ is a rule that assigns a unique (single) element $f(x) \in Y$ to each element $x \in D$_. So it's an even more abstract definition - it refers to it as a _rule_.. Not sure what I can conclude from this :)

Comment: I think the question of whether $f \circ g$ and $c$ are the *same* function is a bit beside the point (even though they are) - the key thing is Robert Israel's comment. If two functions give the same result for each input and one is differentiable, then so is the other one. This is because differentiability only depends on the results of a function, not its definition. I think the major mistake in your reasoning is here: *because the inner $g$ isn't differentiable at $x=0$, the whole composition isn't differentiable at this point*. That's not how you prove something isn't differentiable.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, if you say that the composition is the same as the simplified version, that means that **the Chain Rule is flawed**. Because if I do everything "by the book", I can't apply it to $f\circ g$.

Comment: Ah OK I think we're getting somewhere. This is exactly what the book was getting at - the chain rule says "if two functions are differentiable then their composition is differentiable". This is a *one-way* implication. It doesn't say that this condition is necessary. The point of this example is that there are differentiable compositions that the chain rule can't show is differentiable. This is to be expected - many many useful theorems are about sufficient-but-not-necessary conditions. Note that "differentiable" is a stand-alone definition and it's not defined by the chain rule.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen, aha, now I got it - thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment you write

> A function $f$ from a set $D$ to a set $Y$ is a rule that assigns a unique (single) element $f(x)∈Y$ to each element $x∈D$.

This is a "naive" definition because it does not explain what a *rule* is. I think you understand it as a sort of an algorithm (or a software program) which can be applied
to $x \in D$ and produces an output $f(x) \in Y$. With this understanding one may indeed think that the assigments

$$x \mapsto x^2$$
$$x \mapsto \lvert x \rvert^2$$
$$x \mapsto \lvert x^2 \rvert$$
$$x \mapsto (x+1)^2 - 2x -1$$

are different functions because there are different algorithms to compute the output.

However, this is a *misundestanding*. In mathematics one is usually not interested in the specific steps used to calculate the output, but only in the output itself. As Guillaume Berlat explained in his answer, the modern (though more abstract) point of view is to define a function $f : D \to Y$ as a subset $f \subset D \times Y$ with the property that for each $x \in D$
there exists exactly one $y \in Y$ such that $(x, y) \in f$. In that case one writes $y = f(x)$.

This implies that two functions $\phi , \psi : D \to Y$ are equal if and only if $\phi(x) = \psi(x)$ for all $x \in D$. It is completely irrelevant which computational steps are performed to get $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$. Therefore the above four function are equal because $x^2 = \lvert x \rvert^2 = \lvert x^2 \rvert = (x+1)^2 - 2x - 1$.

Naively again, you may imagine a function as a machine having an inbox and an outbox. You do not know what precisely happens inside the machine. But if two machines produce always the same output for a given input, then it reasonable to regard the machines as identical.

In your example we have the two functions $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb  R, f(x) = x^2$ and $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb  R, g(x) = \lvert x \rvert$. $f$ is differentiable at $x = 0$, but $g$ is not.

We have $g \circ f = f$ because $(g \circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) = \lvert x^2 \rvert = x^2 = f(x)$. This shows that $g \circ f$ is is differentiable at $x = 0$ although $g$ is not.

It does not contradict the chain rule because this rule does not state anything about the differentiability of the composition of functions $f, g$ for which $f$ is not differentiable at $x$ or $g$ is not differentiable at $f(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

A function is what it outputs for given input. Different formulas giving the same output correspond to the same function. So here $c=f\circ g=g\circ f$.

Functions $f:X\rightarrow Y$ can be defined in many ways. A common way is to view them as subsets $S$ of $X\times Y$ (such that for every $x$ there is a unique $y$ s.t. $(x,y)\in S$). This way we can see that different formulas giving the same outputs are in fact intrinsically the same function.

Comment: What if we don't define it as a mapping between sets? :) E.g. during programming, we often can't afford this. So we define them as expressions. And for some input a simplified expression may be valid, while the explicit function composition may be undefined.. Or if we're doing physics, and one of the steps is impossible - we won't be able to perform it - that physical quantity won't be defined. Even though a simplified expression (excluding that quantity) can give an answer.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev The point is that when we talk about 'function', we agree that different formulas that always give the same output are the same. It's like saying $2/2=1/1=1$, these expressions may be different, but the number is the same.

Comment: Of course this works only if they agree everywhere. The functions $f(x)=x/x$ and $f(x)=1$ can be viewed as different as they have different domain.

Comment: Hm.. If so, then the Chain Rule is flawed. Because if I do what the rule says, I can't really apply it to $f\circ g$..

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev The chain rule is not flawed. The chain rule is a condition that implies the composition is differentiable. This is not an equivalence. This question was trying to illustrate this.

Comment: Here's the definition: _if $f(u)$ is differentiable at point $u=g(x)$ and $g(x)$ is differentiable at $x$, then the composite function $(f \circ g)(x)$=f(g(x)) is differentiable at $x$, and $(f \circ g)(x)=f'(g(x))g(x)$_. By this definition, I can't apply this rule and differentiate my composition.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev Yes but not being able to apply the rule to show the composition is differentiable, does not imply that the composition is not differentiable

Comment: Ah.. Now I got it!